# EasyBlog Component of Joomla site breaking FTP download to local files in PHPStorm

Tags: joomla, ftp, phpstorm

I have used PHPStorm frequently to download files locally with the use of FTP, but on a recent attempt to establish a "New Project form existing files..", I was able to establish connection, but could not download from server if the components/com_easyblog was in this request (i.e. including a full transfer). The process shows standard files transferring and then snags on a css folder, generating an infinite of css/css/css/css... before ending process with no explanation. This is the exact path reference

```
components/com_easyblog/themes/hako-new/css/css/css/..
```

I have not ran into this, so if there is any features to debug this in PHPStorm I am open to any suggestions. I can get all files if I skirt around this component, but I really want to solve this for security and to do allow all file downloads.

Comment: This has happened on various alterations to PHP Storm's FTP connections, we are now trying alternative FTP software to see if maybe PHPStorm's FTP is the issue.

Comment: actually the path is 'hako - new' with spaces...

Comment: So that was it, changing directory allowed full FTP, what a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like few ran into this or use the combination, but will answer in-case someone in the future runs into this issue. As I said it was an issue with the spaces, not effecting other FTP's. This is an issue with either PHPStorm or the component of EasyBlog depending how you look at it.